# How to use pstricks with XeLaTeX and tufte-book class?

Tags: xetex, pstricks, tufte-book

I would like to use the beautiful `tufte-book` class together with some pictures created using pstricks. XeLaTeX is needed to work with `pstricks`, however when I run this with the tufte-book class I get the error "Argument of \MakeTextLowerCase has an extra }". It seems that the error is caused by the `\title` command. Below is some minimal code that gives an error (if I remove the `\title` command then it runs correctly).

Is there any way I can use `pstricks` and `tufte-book` class with a title?

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\usepackage{pstricks}

\title{Test title}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture*}(-1,-1)(2,1)
\psline[linewidth=1pt](0,0)(1,0)
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: these days luatex works better than xetex  for pstricks

Answer (score 0):

With this [tufte-common.def](https://hvoss.org/texnik/tufte-common.def) I can run it with `xelatex`  and also with `lualatex` (should be preferred)